# Swift HackerRank Missing Numbers Challenge

Tags: performance, programming-challenge, array, time-limit-exceeded, swift

I'm attempting to solve [the "Missing Numbers" challenge on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/missing-numbers) where I'm tasked with finding missing elements comparing two arrays.

`Foundation`'s `NSCountedSet` is a little pokey on large data sets, I rolled my counted set with a Swift `Dictionary`. I'm able to pass all the test cases with the exception of the last case which has ~10,000 elements in each array.

I looked through some of the comments for hints on how to complete the challenge, but they're all in other languages with uncommented code and non-descriptive variable naming.

```
// I put this in to save non-HackerRank users the hassle of getting inputs
let firstArrayCount = Int(readLine()!)! // unused
let listA = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map({Int($0)!})
let secondArrayCount = Int(readLine()!)! // unused
let listB = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map({Int($0)!})

// This is my method to create a countedSet
func countedSet(array: [Int]) -> Dictionary<Int, Int> {
    var dict = Dictionary<Int, Int>()

    for element in array {
        if dict[element] == nil {
            dict[element] = 1
        } else {
            dict[element] = dict[element]! + 1
        }
    }

    return dict
}

// Works fine on everything except large data sets
func missingNumbers(listA: [Int], listB: [Int]) -> String {
    var output: [Int] = []

    let comparisonSet = Set(listB) // list be is larger

    let ctdSetListA = countedSet(array: listA)
    let ctdSetListB = countedSet(array: listB)

    for element in comparisonSet {
        if ctdSetListA[element] != ctdSetListB[element] {
            output.append(element)
        }
    }

    return output.sorted().map({String($0)}).joined(separator: " ")
}
```

I welcome suggestions on how to speed up my code. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "create or update" in the `countedSet` function
can be simplified using the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
func countedSet(array: [Int]) -> Dictionary<Int, Int> {
    var dict = Dictionary<Int, Int>()
    for element in array {
        dict[element] = (dict[element] ?? 0) + 1
    }
    return dict
}
```

This also saves one dictionary lookup if the value is already present in the dictionary.

I would (but that may be a matter of personal preference) separate the string
conversion completely from the difference computation. Return an integer 
array from `missingNumbers`:

```
func missingNumbers(listA: [Int], listB: [Int]) -> [Int]
```

and do the string conversion at the call site:

```
let missing = missingNumbers(listA: listA, listB: listB)
print(missing.map({String($0)}).joined(separator: " "))
```

or print the numbers directly, without string conversion:

```
let missing = missingNumbers(listA: listA, listB: listB)
for num in missing {
    print(num, terminator: " ")
}
print()
```

The `comparisonSet` in the `missingNumbers` function is not needed. Since B is
the "larger" set, it suffices to iterate over the counted set generated from B:

```
func missingNumbers(listA: [Int], listB: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var output: [Int] = []

    let ctdSetListA = countedSet(array: listA)
    let ctdSetListB = countedSet(array: listB)

    for (element, count) in ctdSetListB {
        if ctdSetListA[element] != count {
            output.append(element)
        }
    }

    return output.sorted()
}
```

The next improvement is to use only one counted set: Add the elements from B
and subtract the elements from A. Then check which elements have a positive count
in the end:

```
func missingNumbers(listA: [Int], listB: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    var ctdSet = countedSet(array: listB)
    for element in listA {
        ctdSet[element]! -= 1 // We know that elements in A are present in B
    }

    let output = ctdSet.filter { $0.value > 0 }.map { $0.key }
    return output.sorted()
}
```

Generally, a "filter + map" operation can be optimized with `flatMap`:

```
    let output = ctdSet.flatMap { $0.value > 0 ? $0.key : nil }
```

The essential clue however is (I assume) the given constraint

> The difference between maximum and minimum number in B is less than or equal to 100.

which means that we can use a fixed sized array to keep track of the number of
occurrences of each number, and all
dictionary lookups now become "simple" array subscript operations. 
This also makes sorting the missing numbers redundant:

```
func missingNumbers(listA: [Int], listB: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    guard let minValue = listB.min() else { return [] } // Empty input

    var counts = Array(repeating: 0, count: 101)
    for elem in listB {
        counts[elem - minValue] += 1
    }
    for elem in listA {
        counts[elem - minValue] -= 1
    }

    var output: [Int] = []
    for i in counts.indices {
        if counts[i] > 0 {
            output.append(i + minValue)
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

The final for loop creating the output array also can be written concisely in a functional
way as

```
    let output = counts.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element > 0 ? $0.offset + minValue : nil }
```

Another possible performance bottleneck is when the input data is read:

```
let listA = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map({Int($0)!})
```

The input lines can contain up to 1,000,010 integers, which means
that *many* temporary string are created. An alternative is to use
`Scanner` from the Foundation framework to read integers directly
from the string. And since the number of integers is known, we
can call `reserveCapacity()` to avoid reallocations while the
array grows:

```
func splitToIntegers(_ s: String, count: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] = []
    result.reserveCapacity(count)
    var n = 0
    let scanner = Scanner(string: s)
    while scanner.scanInt(&n) {
        result.append(n)
    }
    return result
}

let firstArrayCount = Int(readLine()!)!
let listA = splitToIntegers(readLine()!, count: firstArrayCount)
let secondArrayCount = Int(readLine()!)!
let listB = splitToIntegers(readLine()!, count: secondArrayCount)
```

This turned out to be much faster in my test.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation of how to trim down my bloated code! Despite trimming it down, I'm still timing out on the the final test case.

Comment: @Adrian: See update :)

Comment: It appears not using `Scanner` was my bottleneck! I've learned many things with this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An idea to solve this problem is the following

Sort A and B. Now we compare the elements of the list in that way

```
    i = j = 0
    while i < n and j < m 
        if A[i] != B[j]                     
            print B[j]                      //We know that B[j] are not in A[i] because the numbers are sorted
            while j<m and B[j] == B[j+1]    //Move j while B[j] equal to B[j+1], this is because we already count that number
                j = j+1
        else
            j = j + 1
            i = i + 1
```